# laravel path of files in (windows) localhost

Tags: php, laravel

This test is on localhost/windows/php/apache/mysql

For example:

in root of Public folder:

```
$path = '/upload/images/accounts/12005/thumbnail_profile_eBCeBawXWP.jpg';
```

I want use it:

```
$img->save($path);
```

I get this error:

> "Can't write image data to path
>   (/upload/images/accounts/12005/thumbnail_profile_eBCeBawXWP.jpg)"

I try to fix it:

```
$path = public_path($path);
$img->save($path);
```

So I get this error:

> "Can't write image data to path
>   (D:\Server\data\htdocs\laravel\jordankala.com\public_html\ /upload/images/accounts/12005/thumbnail_profile_pH657T62fl.jpg)

probably, in real server (linux), I won't have this problem and the code words.

Now how can I manage this error? (I want it works in windows localhost and real linux server)

Comment: RTFM: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-app-path

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to save at your path

`$file = $request->file('image_field_name');
$destinationPath = 'upload/images/accounts/12005/';
$uploadedFile = $file->move($destinationPath,$file->getClientOriginalName()); //move the file to given destination path`